# Validating username and password in asp.net webapi core project

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on a webapi core project and I need to salt and hash users password when created.
i found this code online which might help to do this for asp.net core.

How do I validate username and password when user login to the system?

```
    using System;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a password: ");
            string password = Console.ReadLine();

            // generate a 128-bit salt using a secure PRNG
            byte[] salt = new byte[128 / 8];
            using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
            {
                rng.GetBytes(salt);
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Salt: {Convert.ToBase64String(salt)}");

            // derive a 256-bit subkey (use HMACSHA1 with 10,000 iterations)
            string hashed = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
                password: password,
                salt: salt,
                prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1,
                iterationCount: 10000,
                numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));
            Console.WriteLine($"Hashed: {hashed}");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The salt also needs to be save, generally just prefix the hash with the salt.

On verification get the salt, run the `KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2` again and compare the resulting hashes.